# Adding comments to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Until I think rails 5 (inclusive), one could add comments to the migration file, which then is dumped to the schema file. Will it be supported with rails 6 also ?

Thanks for any information.

Comment: more information - we are using PostgresSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Rails 5 the support of adding comments in migrations was implemented https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22911

the code is still present in the 6.0 stable branch
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_creation.rb#L88

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not clear as to the syntax, how to add a comment.

Comment: @dani I think it will remain the same as the current implementation judging from the spec of this feature in the 6.0 branch https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/61f5e1c0f1a034965407610b479afb1dc5deeace/activerecord/test/cases/comment_test.rb#L23-L27